# How to access environment variables during Capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger, rbenv

I have my rails (4.2) app running through Passenger (5.0.28) + Apache (2.4.7) on an Ubuntu (14.02) system, ruby (2.3.0) managed with rbenv . I deploy with Capistrano (3.4.0).

All my environment variables are set in a very simple `profile.d` script.

```
#!/bin/sh
export VAR1=VAL1
export VAR2=VAL2
```

This works like a charm. My app `ENV` has all the correct variables, `Secrets.yml` is properly populated... everything works EXCEPT for when deploying with Capistrano over ssh.

In my `deploy.rb` I have the following that I think is relavant:

```
set :ssh_options, {
forward_agent: true,
paranoid: true,
keys: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}
```

Capistrano docs being incredibly limited and ssh\server config not my strong point I can't seem to figure out why my `ENV` variables aren't seen by Capistrano. If I run `puts ENV.inspect` during the deploy flow, I get things such as `"TERM_PROGRAM"=>"Apple_Terminal"` and my local machine user info and whatnot. Why isn't Capistrano using the remote environment? How can I amend my configuration either server side or in my deploy script to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I think some clarification of terminology and Capistrano's execution model is needed.

Capistrano is a program that runs on your local machine. So `ENV` within Capistrano sees your local environment, not the server's. There is no way for Capistrano to "see" the remote `ENV` with plain Ruby code because the Ruby code that makes up Capistrano is not executing there.

What Capistrano *does* do is use SSH to send commands to the server to be executed there. Commands like `mkdir`, `bundle install`, and so on.

To see this illustrated, add a Capistrano task to your deployment flow that does this:

```
task :puts_remote_env do
  on roles(:all) do
    remote_env = capture("env")
    puts remote_env
  end
end
```

This will run the `env` command on the remote server, capture the result, and print it to your console.

I hope this makes it more clear how Capistrano works.

---

So, as you can see from the `puts_remote_env` output, the variables defined in your `profile.d` script are not there. Why?

It is because Capistrano is using a **non-login, non-interactive SSH session**. In that SSH session, your `profile.d` script is not being evaluated. This is explained in detail in the Capistrano FAQ: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

You need to find another way to set those variables other than `profile.d` script.

You could specify them in your Capistrano configuration itself (e.g. `production.rb`) like this:

```
set :default_env, { var1: "val1", var2: "val2" }
```

Capistrano will then explicitly set up that environment when it executes SSH commands.

Or you could use a tool like [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), which allows Rails to read variables variables from a special file instead of relying on the execution environment.

Or you could experiment with different dot file locations to see if there are some that are still evaluated even in a non-login, non-interactive session. On Ubuntu, I've had success exporting variables at the very top of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write that. That chart at the end of the link is fantastic.